# Initiating observable collection then accessing that collection from multiple classes/methods

Tags: c#, wpf

Fairly new to C# and WPF, so apologies if this is obvious.

I have converted a console app into a WPF application, and what I wanted to do was pass all the `Console.WriteLine` lines to an observable collection, to then write the newly added lines to a text box, to show the progress in the UI.

The issue I have is that there are multiple classes that I want to write to this ObservableCollection from, and this is the point I am stuck at.

Here is how I have approached this so far...

**Model** - I have the observable collection defined:

```
public class Progress
    {

        private ObservableCollection<string> _GGProgress = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> GGProgress
        {
            get { return _GGProgress; }
            set { _GGProgress = value; }
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** - Create instance of the progress class and attach a CollectionChanged event to it:

```
//Initiage the Progress class
 Progress prog = new Progress();

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            prog.GGProgress.CollectionChanged += GGProgress_CollectionChanged;

        }

private void GGProgress_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
            {
                GGImportProgress.Text += e.NewItems[0];
            }
        }
```

I can then call this within the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
prog.GGProgress.Add("Text added");
```

And it will update the textbox as expected. From the MainWindow.xaml.cs however, I will initiate further classes, and within those classes, I could initiate further classes, and it is from all these classes I want to be able to update the observable collection and have it update that text box in the UI.

I tried initiating the Progress class, and then accessing it through the class I initiated it from, but I soon hit circular references.

I can look at rewriting the whole thing, but I wondered if I was missing something and there is an elegant solution for me to implement to be able to update that observable collection from different nested classes?

I am not using MVVM at present, as I presumed that this would be an small 'easy' app, but will happily switch if it makes life easier.

Comment: MVVM will make life easier, yes. Sounds like your OC should be in a model class that is injected/shared into all other classes (heck, you could even use a service locator at first) and then the view could bind to it.

Comment: Thanks - will look into that. When you say 'injected/shared' could you point me in the direction of some resource to show how that is achieved?

Comment: @Leonidas199x By the way, a cleaner way to display the progress messages would be `<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding GGProgress}" />`  in the appropriate view. Let the UI worry about handling CollectionChanged.

Comment: You could wrap the OC in a logging "service" and inject it with something like NInject